# sending SMS with Twilio

Tags: iphone, sms, twilio

I"m trying to figure this out, sorry if it's too basic of a question.

I have iPhone app with several hundred users.  While they're interacting with my app, I need the ability to send them several SMS messages (max 10).
Say 300 users, using the app once a week, with 10 SMS per use:

300*4*10 * .0075 = $90

There is also a $1 per month phone fee. Is that per phone of my users, or the single Twilio number that I am sending texts from?

I'm hoping it's not per user number, which would make my monthly $390.

I've reached out to Twilio, but still waiting a response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

That charge for the phone number is per number you buy within the Twilio dashboard, it is not per number you are sending to.

So in your calculation, you are spending $91 per month [sending SMS](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages), not $390.

Comment: good news!  thank you.  So, can I do all this with one Twilio number?  Do they limit how many messages can be sent out per Twilio number?  I'll most likely set up an alphanumeric id as well.

Comment: You can indeed do this with one number, the only limit is that your number can only send one message per second. If you set up an alphanumeric id you won't be able to receive messages, but if that isn't a problem for you then go for it!

Comment: This rate is over 400 SMS per day.  They are not unsolicited and users opt-in as part of my app.  Will there be an issue with this many SMS's from one long number?